# How to add header CSV file Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I want to add header for column in CSV file.I am using CSV lib ver 4.0.4 and My code:

```
  List<List<dynamic>> rows = List<List<dynamic>>();
    for (int i = 0; i <rootAttendanceList.length;i++) {
      List<dynamic> row = List();
      row.add(rootAttendanceList[i].name);
      row.add(rootAttendanceList[i].company);
      rows.add(row);
    }
    String dir = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).absolute.path;
    String  file = "$dir";
    File f = new File(file+"/myreport.csv");
    String csv = const ListToCsvConverter().convert(rows);
    f.writeAsString(csv);
    print(f.path);
```

It work. but I want to add header.

Answer (score 1):

So basically the structure of CSV file is as follows,

```
Title1,Title2,Title3 (represent headers)
one,two,three (represent 1st row)
example1,example2,example3 (represent 2nd row)
```

```
String csv = const ListToCsvConverter().convert(rows);
f.writeAsString(csv);
print(f.path);
```

here in your code csv is string that is retrieved using function ListToCsvConverter(). Now what you just need to do here is prepend a string containing headers to the String csv.
Let's say your headers are name,address,country then, your code will be something like this.

```
String header = "name,address,country";
String csv = const ListToCsvConverter().convert(rows);
f.writeAsString(csv);
print(f.path);
```

But here as you can see in CSV file string every row has end of line. and every record is separated by "," symbol. So you have to tell ListToCsvConverter() function about these two using it's parameter "fieldDelimiter" and "eol".
So here is the final code with adding endofline (eol) to our header string and passing parameter to function

```
String header = "name,address,country\n";
String csv = const ListToCsvConverter(
  fieldDelimiter: ",",
  eol: "\n"
).convert(rows);
f.writeAsString(csv);
print(f.path);
```

I hope this would help you and the others facing same problem. I know there will be lot typo mistakes but I hope you understand the concept I'm explaining. For more clarity you can check my code [Here](https://github.com/nadewell/trading_book/blob/master/lib/database.dart). Simply go through function backupDB().

Please let me know if I'm wrong some where and help me correct it. Thank you for giving time to my solution. Have nice day.